# Symbolic Link in Windows Azure Web Sites?

Tags: git, azure, symlink, azure-web-app-service

We're looking at running Drupal sites in Azure Web Sites, and deploying via Git. Virtual Machines could support it, but we just wanted to know if Web Sites were an option also.

The goal is to have the following Git repo structure:

- `Drupal` (submodule to drupal.org main project, **with symlink to `Sites`** below)
- `Sites` (with `all/modules/contrib` as submodules)
- Other meta stuff like Deploy tools, Dependencies, etc.

As far as I have read, it appears that Azure Web Sites doesn't support symlinks. I can't say it's surprising, but I wanted to be sure.

Comment: I'd like to get some more details about this... Could you update your Question with the folder structure you're proposing? and what you're trying to achieve with these symlinks? I assume it's to move your modules to a more secure folder?

Comment: Thanks for following up, SyntaxC4. We've decided to use the Drupal-prescribed structure at http://drupal.org/node/803746.